# Bad request by form submitting

Tags: go, templates, csrf

I have two files:

base.layout.gohtml
main.page.gohtml

I also have a file server, which was created with http.FileServer.

As a multiplexer I use [chi](https://github.com/go-chi/chi).
This file server I use in .Handle() method in chi.
I also use package [nosurf](https://github.com/justinas/nosurf) for CSRF protection.
Then I have handler for get requests, in which I add new token to the page in a map before rendering.

Then I take the token on the page:

```
<form action="/address" method="post">
 <label for="CSRFToken">
   <input type="hidden" id="CSRFToken" name="csrf_token" value="{{.CSRFToken}}"/>
 </label>
 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Click</button>
</form>
```

The problem is that when the page is rendered by the first time, token is in input. And that is ok. But, if I submit the form, then already post handler handles this request (also have a function, which brings token to the map), I get an error "bad request".

I solve this problem by adding to the page this section:

```
{{template "base" .}}
```

But I cannot understand why it works by the first rendering get request) without

```
{{template "base" .}}
```

and does not work by the second (post request).